# PARAMETRO TABLE EN UNA FUNCION POSTGRESQL

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, vb

estoy tratando de enviar una tabla como parametro en una funcion postgresql, y en visual basic me sale el siguiente error:

> "No hay ninguna asignación de tipo de objeto System.Data.DataTable a un tipo nativo de un proveedor administrado conocido."

este es el codigo de postgresql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_adm_artefacto(
V_SERIE character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
V_TIPO_ARTEFACTO integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
V_MODELO character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
V_MARCA integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
V_DETALLE TYPE_DETALLE_AC DEFAULT NULL,
v_usuario integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
V_ID_ARTEFACTO integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_tipo_operacion character DEFAULT NULL::bpchar)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 

AS $BODY$

DECLARE 

    VL_ID_ARTEFACTO INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF V_TIPO_OPERACION = 'I' THEN

        INSERT INTO DETALLE_AC(ID_DETALLE_AC,ID_ARTEFACTO,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,
                               USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION)
        SELECT 1,1,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW() FROM V_DETALLE;

    END IF;


END;


$BODY$;
```

este es el codigo en vb :

```
Sub ADMINISTRAR_ARTEFACTO(ByVal P As E_ARTEFACTO)
    Dim CONECTION As New OdbcConnection
    Try
        CONECTION.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ALURHE_DBConnectionString_64").ConnectionString + ";pwd=2007211050"
        Dim COMMAND As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("{call SP_ADM_ARTEFACTO (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}", CONECTION)

        With COMMAND

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_SERIE", P.P_SERIE)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_TIPO_ARTEFACTO", P.P_TIPO_ARTEFACTO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_MODELO", P.P_MODELO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_MARCA", P.P_MARCA)

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_DETALLE", P.P_DETALLE)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_USUARIO", P.P_USUARIO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_ID_ARTEFACTO", If(P.P_TIPO_OPERACION = "M", P.P_ID_ARTEFACTO, DBNull.Value))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_TIPO_OPERACION", P.P_TIPO_OPERACION)


        End With


        'If P.P_TIPO_OPERACION = "M" Then
        '    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_PRODUCTO", P.P_ID_PRODUCTO)
        'End If

        CONECTION.Open()
        COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CONECTION.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        If (CONECTION.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            CONECTION.Close()
        End If

        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

he tratado de probar llamando solo a la funcion de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT sp_adm_artefacto('1321321',1,'F-14',1,(1,10,5,50),1,NULL,'I')
```

y me sale el error :

```
ERROR:  no existe la relación «v_detalle»
LINE 3: ...NTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW() FROM V_DETALLE
                                                          ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO DETALLE_AC(ID_DETALLE_AC,ID_ARTEFACTO,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,
                               USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION)
        SELECT 1,1,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW() FROM V_DETALLE
CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL sp_adm_artefacto(character varying,integer,character varying,integer,type_detalle_ac,integer,integer,character) en la línea 9 en sentencia SQL
SQL state: 42P01
```

Comment: me parece que el problema esta del lado de VB. probaste el SP solo?

Comment: no lo hecho aun, pruebo y te aviso, gracias

Comment: Es lo primero que tenias que probar :/.. y tambien poner el codigo de la llamada...

Comment: el codigo de la llamada: SELECT sp_adm_artefacto('1321321',1,'F-14',1,(1,10,5,50),1,NULL,'I')     ..... Me sale el siguiente error : no existe la relación «v_detalle»

Comment: probaste tu SP?? podes mostrar el codigo de llamada completo. el codigo VB que se ejecuta. usa el boton [edit] y pone toda la informacion en la pregunta

Comment: ya probe el sp,, y tambien ya edite la pregunta

Comment: me parece que estas llamando mal al SP.. porque usas select? o porque haces call y lo pones entre comillas? pone solo el nombre del SP al object.

Comment: La llamada la hago en postgresql : SELECT "sp_adm_artefacto"('1321321',1,'F-14',1,(1,10,5,50),1,NULL,'I')

Comment: pero entonces el SP no anda

Comment: como haria para crear una funcion en postgresql para que reciba como parametro una tabla ?